# Change to default start folder for Windows command prompt

Tags: windows, windows-xp, command-line

My new Windows XP work computer's command prompt automatically brings up "`H:\>`" when I open it.  Is there a way for me to change that safely?  Specifically, to "`C:\foo\bar\Something Else`"?  I found the method of changing the `Autorun` value through Google, but it came with a warning that it "might affect the functionality of batch scripts."

Bonus note: I was originally getting at this issue in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp), but I didn't ask very directly.  The answer I ended up accepting was really good, so I wanted to leave it there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command prompt automatically starts in the Home Directory specified in your user profile.

A "workaround" to avoid messing with scripts and such is to create a new shortcut to `cmd.exe`.

- Create a new shortcut to `%systemroot%\system32\cmd.exe`
- Once the shortcut is created, right-click and select `Properties`
- In the Shortcut tab, set the "Start in" field to the path you want to start in, ie, `C:\foo\bar\Something Else`
- Click OK and try your new shortcut!

Answer (score 10):

**First method : Execute a change-directory command when cmd starts**

From ["How to change the default startup directory for Command Prompt?"](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/autoruncmd.htm):

Click Start, Run, and type Regedit.exe.
Navigate to the following branch:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

On Windows 10 update 1909, the key is rather in the following location.
No reboot is required.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Command Processor
```

In the right-pane, double-click Autorun and set the startup folder path as its data, preceded by "CD /d ".
If Autorun value is missing, you need to create it, of type String in the above location.

Example:  To set the startup directory to F:\Windows, set the Autorun value data to "CD /d F:\Windows".

**Second method : Change user's home folder**

Right-click "My computer" and choose Manage.
Select "Local users and Groups" and then Users.
Double-click the user in question and go to the Profile tab.
Set in "Home folder" the required directory as the value of "Local path" and do OK.

Comment: you need to logoff and back for changes to take effect, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a desktop shortcut with: `cmd /k cd "Initial folder path"` and use it to open command prompt in that specific folders.

Comment: This is THE answer; trust me.