# Customised command prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Is it possible to customise command prompt to open at a particular directory? For example, my mercurial repositories are all stored at `C:\dev\repo`. Obviously it makes things easier if  I can customise command prompt to open here by default.

Comment: Duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/49575, "Change to default start folder for Windows XP command prompt"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one of the [Microsoft's free PowerToys](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/Downloads/powertoys/Xppowertoys.mspx), which is [CmdHere.exe](http://download.microsoft.com/download/whistler/Install/2/WXP/EN-US/CmdHerePowertoySetup.exe).

This PowerToy adds an "Open Command Window Here" context menu option on file system folders, giving you a quick way to open a command window (cmd.exe) pointing at the selected folder.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You need to create a shortcut to cmd.exe and in the Shortcut's properties edit the Start In field.

Also, take a look at the Colors tab - I have different colour schemes for different tasks so I can immediately distinguish which I am using when I have many open.

[image: Create Shortcut]

[image: Shortcut Title]

[image: Shortcut Properties]

[image: AV CMD]

[image: SVN CMD]

[image: System CMD]

Comment: Thanks for the help, worked a treat. Ive actually used this process to run powershell instead.