# Running Windows XP Command Line from CMD.exe does not load autorun processor batch file

Tags: windows-xp, command-line, alias

I have a batch file set to load up when the Windows XP command line (cmd.exe) starts (using the registry key Command Processor [as detailed](https://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp/115259#115259)).

Unexpectedly, the batch file only runs under certain conditions, based on how the command line is started.

If the command line is started from `Start|All Programs|Accessories|Command Prompt`, the batch file runs.

If the command line is started from `Start|Run|cmd` or `Start|Run|cmd.exe` or via a ssh session through WinSSHD, the batch file does not run.

Is there a way to make the autorun work in all cases?

Comment: Which of the linked solution(s) did you try?

Comment: And is Start|Run picking up a different cmd.exe?

Comment: "This works a treat if the command line is started from the command line executable..." - are you referring to command.com?

Comment: @techie007 I linked to the exact solution.

Comment: @Rhys & w3d I rephrased the question, hopefully the edit answers your questions. Not using command.com

Comment: @Rhys just realized what you were asking. I'm not sure how to answer definitively. Suggestions? The task manager shows the process as `cmd.exe` in every case.

Comment: @Noel - In the answer under the one you tried, they meniton one difference that _may_ be what you're running into.  The answer you linked suggests changing the HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun value. The one below suggests also changing the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE one as well. Just a thought. :)

Comment: @techie007 good catch, and I actually did set both.

Comment: Maybe try one of the other solutions then? Or have a good read of http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/cmd.mspx?mfr=true which is the definitive documentation.  There's a matching Old New Thing entry here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/21/6447771.aspx that talks about how to check whether it's set. I'd suggest running this from your cmd prompt to see what you're actually picking up in each case