# Is there something like Command Substitution in Windows CLI?

Tags: windows, command-line

In Linux (Bash), there's a way to use a command as a parameter for another command, using back-ticks:

```
> echo ===== `time` =====
```

This would print:

> ===== The current time is: 12:22:34.68 =====

Is there a way to do this in cmd.exe on WIndows ?

Comment: see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/434038/whats-the-cmd-powershell-equivalent-of-back-tick-on-bash)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2768608/batch-equivalent-of-bash-backticks

Comment: Also see this this post ([use of doskey command from cmd](http://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp))

Comment: @misterjaytee: Command substitution and aliases are different things.

Comment: @grawity - Thanks for pointing that out - Note to self: must read the question properly before responding...

Comment: That's not what `time` does.

Comment: @Mark That's what `time` does on Windows...

Comment: @Cristi: Linux isn't Windows. On Linux, `time` measures how long it takes a script to execute.

Comment: [What's the cmd/PowerShell equivalent of back tick on Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434038/995714)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo. ===== %time% =====
```

I know this may not be what you want, because you mentioned *command substitution*... So this may be it:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`date/time/t`) do @echo.  ===== %i =====
```

For more details about the usage of `usebackq` try this command:

```
for /?
```

Comment: Yep,  `for /f` is what I was looking for. Thanks! On a side note: It's so kludgy and hard to remember (compared to the bash way).  I should give up "bat programming" and learn something more productive - PowerShell maybe?

Comment: @CristianDiaconescu Why not just use Linux? It's a much superior OS to Windows, especially for devs.

Comment: I am seeing errors that `& was unexpected at this time` running your commands. OS: windows 10. Are you sure this is the correct way?

Answer (score 3):

No, but here is the workaround:

```
D:\>time /t
08:18 PM

D:\>time /t > time.tmp

D:\>set /p time=<time.tmp

D:\>echo == %time% ==
== 08:18 PM ==
```

See also: [Batch equivalent of Bash backticks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2768608/55075).

Answer (score 2):

In Windows the '( )' operator has a similar behavior as the Bash command substitution.

This Linux script:

```
my_linux_variable=$(ls)
my_alternate_linux_variable=`ls`

echo $my_linux_command=$(ls)
echo $my_alternate_linux_command=`ls`
```

gives a similar result as Windows PowerShell:

```
$my_windowsPS_variable = (dir)

$my_windowsPS_variable
```

and as Windows CMD:

```
set my_windowsCMD_variable=(dir)
%my_windowsCMD_variable%
```

Comment: Windows CMD example is wrong.  Parens in cmd shell just execute a command in a subshell.  The env var is set to "(dir)" and it is executed on the second line (when the env var is surrounded by %) - not really the substitution you want.

Comment: this is incorrect for windows cmd.exe behavior

Comment: This is powershell, whereas the question is about cmd.exe

Comment: neat trick; it's like passing by reference instead of by value: ie. the value of dir is actually processed/calculated in 2nd line, and the variable is storing the command, not the result of the command; similar to `doskey`

Comment: `In Windows the '( )' operator has a similar behavior as the Bash command substitution.` this is absolutely wrong. Windows isn't a shell like bash, and cmd doesn't work that way. It should be *In powershell the '( )' operator...*