# Setting environment variables for Windows cmd temporarily, to run a program, in a single line?

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

I have seen [Setting and getting Windows environment variables from the command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/79612/setting-and-getting-windows-environment-variables-from-the-command-prompt), but my question is slightly different.

Say I have a terminal program, `myprogram.c` -> `myprogram.exe`, which reads environment variables; say:

```
...
char *valueMYVAR = getenv("MYVAR");
printf("MYVAR is %s\r\n", (valueMYVAR==NULL)?"":valueMYVAR );
...
```

Now, if I'm in Linux `bash`, I can set the environment variable temporarily, just for that execution of the program, by simply writing it out on the command line, as in:

```
$ MYVAR=1 ./myprogram.exe
```

How could I do the same, if I am using the Windows Command Prompt (`cmd.exe`)? I have tried:

```
> SET MYVAR=1 myprogram.exe
```

... but it doesn't work - in the sense that `myprogram.exe` is not run at all, probably being interpreted as being part of the command line for the `SET` command.

Is this kind of a thing doable in Windows Command Prompt? If relevant, I use Windows 10.

---

EDIT: Found these:

[Is there something like Command Substitution in WIndows CLI?](https://superuser.com/questions/289344/is-there-something-like-command-substitution-in-windows-cli)

> In Windows the '( )' operator has a similar behavior as the Bash command substitution.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8055371/how-do-i-run-two-commands-in-one-line-in-windows-cmd

> Like this on all Microsoft OSes since 2000, and still good today:
>   `dir & echo foo`

So, I've tried:

```
> (SET MYVAR=1 && myprogram.exe)
```

... and this actually works - except, it seems the parentheses in Windows are not a "subshell" (or "subprocess"), and therefore setting the value "leaks" onto the current shell, which I don't want (in other words, if I just run `myprogram.exe` after the above command, it will still pick up `MYVAR=1`, whereas on Linux, `MYVAR` in that case would remain unset).

So, is there a way to do this on a single command line - *and* temporarily?

Comment: Thanks @Biswapriyo - that looks like it will work; though it would have been nice not to have to remember to "unset" the variable in the end

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could run a batch file with a `setlocal`

or on cmd line start another cmd.exe which inherits the current environment but changes are volatile.

```
cmd /c "SET MYVAR=1&myprogram.exe"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @LotPings - the starting of another cmd.exe does exactly what I wanted (makes the environment variable changes not persistent)

Answer (score 4):

Try this command:

```
set Foo=bar & abc.exe & set Foo=
```

This command does:

1. Set `Foo` variable with `bar` value.
2. Run `abc.exe`command.
3. Unset `Foo` variable by adding blank value.

Comment: `The ampersand (&) character is not allowed. The & operator is reserved for future use; wrap an 
ampersand in double quotation marks ("&") to pass it as part of a string.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmpersandNotAllowed`

Comment: @KarlMorrison What do you mean by that? Are you using Command Prompt at all? This question is about in Command Prompt, not in Powershell.

Comment: That was using the command prompt I'm afraid! LotPings solution worked though.