# Writing out to a file based off of the output of the command

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, batch, ms-dos

I have seen many examples of how to create a file through command line using a static name but I need to get it to show a dynamic name based off of my commands output. What I mean by this is the following:

I run the command `npm -v` and it returns `6.4.1` I can easily write that out to the inside of a file but I want the filename to be `6.4.1` if that is what the command returns. So if it returns `8.15.1` then the filename would be `8.15.1`.

Any idea how to do that? I need this to be able to run on windows 7/10 machines so I can verify versions of npm and resolve version mismatches.

Answer (score 1):

[This previous question](https://superuser.com/a/293742/206587) asked the more general question about the equivalent of bash backticks in the Windows commandline.

For your question, example syntax would be as follows:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=*" %i in (`npm -v`) do echo %i > %i
```

The above would write the output of `npm -v` to a file with a name of the version of npm.