# How can I set up a textual shortcut to launch a Program from the start->run dialog box?

Tags: windows-xp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create an alias in Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp)

I want to launch a Program from the start->run dialog box. When I write "DEMO client"(without the quotes) it should launch the Program

Comment: You're new here, aren't you.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams  Well obviously Sherlock, why do you think it says they have one post .  That is no excuse for a nonsensical question though.

Comment: I suppose he's asking about textual shortcuts to paunch programs from the start..run dialog box.  He wants his textual shortcut to be "DEMO client" without the quotes. I've rewritten his question so it makes sense

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way of doing this is to add a shortcut to the program in the `PATH` variable. What you name the shortcut will be what you type into the run box, as renaming the executable will undoubtedly cause problems.

Click `Start`
Right click `My Computer` and click `Properties`
Click on the `Advanced` tab and click on `Enivronment Variables`
Find the `PATH` variable and add the shortcut that points to your program, separated from the others by a `;`.

Alternatively you can do this through the registry at the key

`HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly a double word name will not work for this trick as it will count the first word as program and second as parameter. You can have "_"(underscore) instead of a space. To do that taking "DEMO_Client"...

Just create a shortcut of that app and name the shortcut "DEMO_Client" and place it in `C:\Windows\System32` or add the Shortcut location to `PATH` variable (Not suggested as it will add all the files in that folder into path variable). Placing it in `C:\Windows\System32` is better. It will launch the shortcut when you will type that in `Run`.

This is a simple trick.

Answer (score -1):

Use autohotkey, a freeware.
Get it from [here](http://www.autohotkey.com/download/), install it.

Add this script to the autohotkey.ahk that would be created in your documents automatically:

```
your string goes here::
Run path\program.exe
return
```

this will run the program when you type those letters ANYWHERE...
It does not matter whether they are getting typed or not.
Just sending those letters from keyboard will launch the program.
make sure you choose the text carefully...

If you insist on running that program from "Run" box directly, add the path to the program to **PATH** environment variable.