# Using system variables without % tags in windows command prompt windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I created a shortcuts for my mostly used applications such as notepad, sublime etc.. So everytime I have to create and edit a file I just type %notepad% filename.txt, this conveniently opens notepad.exe and asks me if I want to create a file called filename.txt. It makes it feel like I am using ubuntu :D

How ever I find it annoying to type % everytime I want to use this.  Is there a way I could maybe create a shortcut for this too ?

Also once in command prompt how do I elevate myself to admin ?  Like in ubuntu I type sudo to do this.

Comment: Just don't use the %.  Typing `notepad filename.txt` performs the behavior you describe above for me.  Also, to run a program as a different user, use the `runas` command.  Simply type `runas /help` for more information.  However, I generally prefer to simply right-click on the command prompt shortcut, and select "Run as Administrator," as @Slowki mentioned before.

Comment: I seem to have changed a setting somewhere I guess cause neither runas works nor does the notepad filename.txt directly ! Both of them return the standard "the command is not recognized as internal or a external command"

Comment: Ever since I uninstalled cygwin I am not able to use runas command as well as run notepad as command. I get the standard " Command not recognized as internal or external command"

Comment: @Aditya if you open a `cmd.exe` and type `set path` do you see `%systemroot%` in the variable? If so, your variables are messed up and you need to change your registry. (You need to change the path type from reg_sz to reg_expand_sz.) Let us know if that's the case and we'll tell you where to find the key.

Comment: This is the Output
C:\Users\Aditya>set path
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Rational\common;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\DLLs;C:\Pyth
on27\Lib;C:\Python27\Lib\lib-tk;C:\Python27\scripts;C:\Python27\django\bin;C:\Pr
ogram Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\Program Files\Apache Softwar
e Foundation\lib\servlet-api.jar;.;;C:\Program Files (x86)\Rust\bin;D:\;C:\Progr
am Files (x86)\Rational\common;C:\PROGRA~2\FLASHM~1
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

Comment: @Aditya Wow, your path setting in the registry is ok (no %systemroot%) but your path itself is really screwed up. I don't see the `C:\Windows` and `C:\Windows\System32` at all. Clean Windows 7 has default path `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ `. You might want to add these to the beginning of your system-path in the environment dialog. After that your `notepad textfile.txt` will work again. Like [so](http://i.imgur.com/zEzJUaK.png).

Comment: That worked ! so did the runas command !! phew ! everything is back to normal :)

Comment: Rik, you should post your answer as an answer.  Aditya, you should then accept that answer.  (Try not to accept answers in the same breath as objecting that they don't work, as you've done.  It confuses everyone.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get admin priveleges(As far as I know) you have to actually right click and press run as administrator.
To run commands like notepad SlowkiIsAwesome.txt the easiest method is to setup aliases, this guide [Create an alias in Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp)  should work, even in Win7

Comment: ever since I uninstalled cygwin I am not able to use alias in dos prompt. could you please repost your earlier reply which you edited out I guess. It was about creating a user function or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a folder, stuff it with batch scripts that do whatever you want, and add the new folder's location to the PATH environment variable ([with SetX](http://ss64.com/nt/setx.html)).
This way, when ever you run something from CMD or Run, they'll search first in your folder too.

If you don't want to create a new folder, then you can just put your batch files in a folder that's already in PATH environment variable.