# Prefix commands in batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, prefix

I am using a batch file to run Grunt with some console customization. I was wondering if there is a way to add grunt and a space to the commands I enter into the console.

Here is my batch file:

```
CD /D "C:\Users\ACCRS\Documents\Grunt"
START cmd /K "grunt & title Grunt & prompt $"
```

It would be good if I could make it so it only add grunt if the command is not recognized without it.

Comment: Are you saying you want Grunt to be part of the interactive command line so that if you issue a command in that window that doesn't have a corresponding way to run, it will try it as if you'd typed grunt first?

Comment: @MarkAllen That's the way I read it. The tricky bit being particularly that Grunt should *only* be used when the normal options fail. So, for `dir` CMD would just process `dir`. But for `gruntcommand`, where it's not a built-in command and isn't a EXE/COM/BAT/etc in %PATH%, CMD should automatically prepend `grunt ` and then process the whole thing as `grunt gruntcommand`.

Comment: Exactly! Is that even possible?

Comment: Kinda? Take a look at the Doskey command (still present in Windows 8.1 regardless of what the link name says) http://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp 

You could try to make aliases for at least all the common grunt commands, I think. Give it a shot!

Comment: I have Windows 7 D:

Comment: Awesome - it's not exactly what you wanted but it's close at least.

Comment: Yeah it works for me.